# How to solve Command line: '/opt/lampp/bin/httpd -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -D SSL -D PHP' error?

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, xampp, lampp

I am getting the below error when I do `tail -2 /opt/lampp/logs/error_log`

`[core:notice] [pid 1085] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/lampp/bin/httpd -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -D SSL -D PHP'`

And my MySQL server is going down almost every 5 minutes.

What can I try?

Comment: did you fix it without reinstall ?

Comment: Yes, I had to do a reinstall.

Comment: reinstalling still give me the same issue..